# Can not output content of the linked list

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

I want to populate `linked list` with the content of a text file.

To implement that, I have created structure that will hold data from one line in the file.

Then I would simply go through lines in file, and add populated structures in a linked `list`.

It seems that I have managed to populate the list properly but I have trouble showing its content.

Here is what I have so far:

*Person.h*

```
#ifndef _Person_h_
#define _Person_h_

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Lista
{
private:
    struct Person
    {
        std::string lastName;
        std::string firstName;
        // other fields ommited for brewity

        Person( const char *lName = "", const char *fName = "" )
        {
            lastName += lName;
            firstName += fName;
        }

        ~Person()
        {
            lastName.clear();
            firstName.clear();
        }
    };

    // my linked list of Persons
    std::list<Person> persons;

public:
    // data comes from a comma delimited file 
    Lista( const char *inputFile, int maxTextLength = 100, char delim = ',' )
    {   
        std::ifstream g;
        g.open(inputFile);

        if( g.is_open() )
        {
            std::string temp( maxTextLength, 0 );

            while( !g.eof() )
            {
                Person p;

                // fill Person structure
                g.getline( &p.lastName[0], maxTextLength, delim );
                g.getline( &p.firstName[0], maxTextLength, delim );

                // add it to the list
                persons.push_back(p);
            }
            g.close();
        }
    }

    // testing function- > it should just display the content of the list
    void print()const
    {
        std::list<Person>::const_iterator it;

        for( it = persons.begin(); it != persons.end(); ++it )
        {
            std::cout << "L: " << it->lastName.c_str() << std::endl
                << "F: " << it->firstName.c_str() << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // emty list
    ~Lista(){ persons.clear(); }
};

#endif
```

I have decided to stop here and test what was done, so I called `print()` function in my main:

*main.cpp*

```
#include "Person.h"

int main()
{
    Lista p( "test comma separated file.txt", 100, ',' );

    p.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler reports no errors but when I run my test program I get this:

```
L:
F:

L:
F:

Press any key to continue...
```

If I add `cout` in `Lista` constructor it outputs names properly. It seems that I do something wrong in my constructor ( maybe it has something to do with temporary `Person` variable being on stack? ) but I do not know what since I am inexperienced.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a buffer to read to. What you did was to create `lastName` string with length of 1 byte and read up to `maxTextLength` bytes into it.

```
//create temporary buffers
char* buffFirstName = new char[maxTextLength];
char* buffLastName = new char[maxTextLength];
while( !g.eof() )
{
    //read into temporary buffers
    g.getline( &buffFirstName[0], maxTextLength, delim );
    g.getline( &buffLastName[0], maxTextLength, delim );
    //create person data
    Person p(buffFirstName, buffLastName);
    // add it to the list
    persons.push_back(p);
}
//release the buffers
delete[] buffFirstName;
delete[] buffLastName;
```

Comment: In C++, you can't write `char buffFirstName[maxTextLength];` as it reports error. Still, I have bypassed it with usage of `string`s. Thank you. Upvoted.

Comment: @user3261013 Oh, sorry my mistake. I thought `maxTextLenght` is a constant or `#define`. The entire point is that dynamically-allocating classes lose all their magic when you use them as `char*`. I hope you've done `string.reserve(maxTextLength)` before passing it to `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person( const char *lName = "", const char *fName = "" )
    {
        lastName += lName;
        firstName += fName;
    }
```

Not sure, but in c++, could you use this for parameter ? :

```
const char *lName = ""
```

I understand what you want (default value) but it set value to "".
Try without it.

Comment: The result remained the same.

Comment: You can use bug tracker like gdb to see step by step what's going on.
Also, shouldn't you use $this->lastName += lName ?